# Error: Apollo has been already created

Tags: angular, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-client

I am fairly new to GraphQL.

What i would like to do is make a call to a GraphQL server on every `onBlur` event on a text Input.

The problem is:

- The call is successfully made only once.
- On the second call, i get this error:

`ERROR Error: Apollo has been already created.`

This may be something pretty obvious, but i can't find a solution.

**Is there a way to successfully make a new graphql call on every `onBlur` event made consecutive times?**

```
onBlurZIP(zip) {
    const zipQuery = gql`
      query {
        getAddressByPostalCode(postalCode: "${zip}") {
            country
            city
            street
            streettype
            state
            stateInitials
            quarter
        }
      }
    `;

    const httpLink = createHttpLink({
      uri: environment.endpoint
    });

    const link = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
      return {
        headers: {
          // headers object...
        }
      }
    });

    this._apollo.create({
      link: link.concat(httpLink),
      cache: new InMemoryCache()
    });

    this.querySubscription = this._apollo.watchQuery<any>({
      query: zipQuery,
      variables: { zip },
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
    })
    .valueChanges
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        // do stuff...
      },

      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

The HTML:

```
<input formControlName="zip" (blur)="onBlurZIP($event.target.value)" type="text" class="form-control" name="zip" id="zip" required>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apollo client instance has to be singleton. You need to define it once in your application and pass it down to components using `<ApolloProvider>`. You can refer to react-apollo documents for the same: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started.html.

Your code is throwing error because you are creating instance of apollo client on every onBlur event.

**Edit:**

Relevant document for initialising apollo client in angular.js: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/setup.html

Comment: Thanks! I found that out a little before seeing your answer.
Actually i'm using Angular, and had to create an instance of apollo in my root `AppModule`. Your answer is right though!

Comment: Sorry about giving react related answer, I did not check angular tag.

Comment: @rbenvenuto will you please give me the reference of code in angular. I got the same error .  How to create an instance of apollo in AppModule?